# How to make sure my dom manipulating function/code is called after the DOM has been rendered?

Tags: javascript, dom, asynchronous, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular app, in which a `model` change triggers a pop-up which is a `directive`. I need to select an element on this pop-up, but the DOM update ('$digest') seems to be asynchronous and as a result it doesn't work for the first time the pop-up is shown/created. This works for subsequent pop-ups. How do I make sure that my code runs after the pop-up has been created and rendered with all the child elements?

Here is the equivalent code:

```
angular.module('mymodule', []).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    require: ngModel,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      element.addClass('foo');
      // And similar stuff
      ctrl.$render = function justRender() {
        if (ctrl.viewValue) {
          element.modal('show');
          /* Here I have code for selecting the contents of the pop-up,
             which doesn't work as DOM is not assuredly rendered at this time.
          */
        } else {
          element.modal('hide');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to "select" an element in this popup ? What do you want to do after selecting ?

Comment: @ganaraj: There is some text being shown in the popup, I need to show it pre-selected for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `$timeout` service of AnguarJS at this purpose.

So you have to wrap your code in a callback... something like:

```
$timeout(function() {
    // your code here
}, 0);
```

`$timeout` is an AngularJS wrapper for the `window.setTimeout`.
It adds a new event in the browser event queue; since the rendering engine is already in this queue, the browser will complete page rendering before processing a new task in the queue.

I wrote an article on my blog about this topic... you could use it as reference when you need to [run code after DOM has been rendered](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `$timeout` runs after the browser rendering. This worked, but I am curious about how to pass parameters to the callback? I couldn't find any way to do this.